# includeと宣言の違いはなんですか

Tags: c++, preprocessor

例えば下の文で、

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

float Myabs(float x);

int main(){
    float a=2.5;
    std::cout<<Myabs(a)<<std::abs(a);
    a=-5.25;
    std::cout<<Myabs(a)<<std::abs(a);
    return 0;
}

float Myabs(float x){return x>0?x:-x;}
```

この文を下の2つの例のように変更すると
例１

```
#include<iostream>

float Myabs(float x);

int main(){
    float a=2.5;
    std::cout<<Myabs(a)<<std::abs(a);
    a=-5.25;
    std::cout<<Myabs(a)<<std::abs(a);
    return 0;
}
#include<cmath>
float Myabs(float x){return x>0?x:-x;}
```

例２

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main(){
    float a=2.5;
    std::cout<<Myabs(a)<<std::abs(a);
    a=-5.25;
    std::cout<<Myabs(a)<<std::abs(a);
    return 0;
}
float Myabs(float x);
float Myabs(float x){return x>0?x:-x;}
```

どちらもエラーが出ます。宣言が無いために出るエラーとインクルードが無いために出るエラーです。
これは、コンパイラから見てinclude文と宣言が同じ動作をすることを示していますか？

Comment: `#include` はファイルの取り込みをします。この場合`#include<cmath>`が必要なのは`abs` の宣言がそこに含まれているからです。つまり読み込んだファイルに宣言が書いてあれば宣言を直接書く代わりになると言う意味で同じ動作と言えます（#include自体が宣言の動作をするというワケではありません）。

Answer (score 2):

コンパイルオプション `-E` を試してみてください。プリプロセッサーによって処理されたソースコードが出力されます。これによって出力されるソースコードこそがC言語やC++言語のソースコードです。そこには `#include` や `#define` `#if` `#endif` などのプリプロセッサ命令は処理されて消えていることが理解できると思います。

Comment: +1プリプロセッサーに言及しているのはこの回答だけですね。

Answer (score 1):

まず、**includeと宣言は異なります。**
`#include`はコンパイル時にファイルの中身を取り込む機能しか持ちません。
通常は`#include`ではヘッダファイルを取り込むのに使われます。ヘッダファイルは、通常は宣言が書かれたファイルです。`iostream`や`cmath`もヘッダファイルであり、`std::cout`や`std::abs`などの宣言が記述されています。このことから、混同していると思われます。

#### 例１

`std::abs` の宣言は `<cmath>` に記述されています。ですが、`#include <cmath>`が登場する前に`std::abs(a)`が登場しているため、宣言が見つからずエラーになります。

#### 例2

`Myabs(a)` が、`float Myabs(float x);`の宣言よりも前に登場しているためエラーになります。